# jQuery ajaxForm "h is undefined" problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have a form that is brought up in a ajaxed modal which I am using for updating user details.  When the modal loads I call a js function:

```
teamCreate: function() {
$j("#step1,form#createEditTeam").show();
$j("#step2").hide();
var options = {
 type: "get",
 dataType: 'json',
     beforeSubmit:  before,  // pre-submit callback 
     success:       success  // post-submit callback
  };
$j("form#createEditTeam").ajaxForm(options);

function before(formData, jqForm, options){ 
 var valid = $j("form#createEditTeam").valid();
 if (valid === true) {
  $j(".blockMsg").block({ message: $j('#panelLoader') });
      return true; // submit the form
 } else {
  $j("form#createEditTeam").validate();
  return false; // prevent form from submitting
 }
};

function success(data){
 if (data.status == "success") {
  $j(".blockMsg").unblock();
 } else {
  //
}
};

function error(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
alert("Error code: " + xhr.statusText);
 };
}
```

This works just fine when I first submit the form, regardless how many times the modal is opened and closed.  However, if I submit the form and then open the modal again and try to submit the form again I get a js error:

`h is undefined`

Comment: I don't see an `h` in your code... does the error reference a file and a line number by any chance?

Comment: `h` is a variable set in the jQuery library.  The line in jQuery that Firebug reports is causing the problem is:

    (function(b){function s(c,a){var e=c==...etHack:4};var k=null,m=[]}})(jQuery); 

I assume `h` is what jQuery is assigning as the DOM object, but I can't figure out why it is not being assigned correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To more quickly debug this, I would strongly suggest changing out the minified version of the JQuery library with the full version of it, then running your code again.  You'd be hard-pressed to figure out the root of the problem using the minified version, but you'd most certainly find it easier to debug if you have the full version running.  The variable and function names would make much more sense.

Comment: So it turns out the problem is not jQuery itself but the blockUi plugin I am using.  It removes a DOM element that it is using in the message array and does not put it back once it has removed itself so subsequent triggers of the blockui error when they can't find the DOM element.  Eugh.